# Tensorflow : Check failed: NDIMS == dims() (2 vs. 1)

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

I get the following error after building the graph of my NN.
when I try to execute :

`loss, _ = self._sess.run([self.loss_op, self.train_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)`

I get this error :

> F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.cc:36] Check failed: NDIMS ==
>   dims() (2 vs. 1) Asking for tensor of 2 dimensions from a tensor of 1
>   dimensions

I don't succeed to know to which part of the graph this error is related to ...
Because, normaly the graph is build, so shapes should be correct ... are not ?
Do you have a idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a bug in TensorFlow, because it should never be possible to trigger such a hard error from the Python interface. It's difficult to figure out a workaround without known which ops you are running, so can you share more code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I am confused, but I can not share all my code. My graph is a quite complexe. I use a lot of standard tensorflow's function, and two dynamic_rnn. Do you have an idea to were a should look ?

Comment: There are many possible code paths into that error message, so I'm not sure what the most likely candidate is. It might be worth checking any `tf.transpose()` calls, because these are often used to transform input data in an RNN, and they seem to call through to code that *could* raise such an error (but it looks like they check the inputs first, so this failure *should* not happen).

Comment: I found to source of the error. It came from an external op that I created. One of the input tensor of this op didn't have the good shape. It is very difficulte to find the error when I got only this line of error... Maybe some thing to improve in Tensorflow. Thanks a lot for your reply !